# How to trigger VBA Workbook_SheetCalculate Event?

Tags: vba, excel

I tried Workbook_SheetCalculate Event and tried to trigger it, but it did not work, although I recalculated the worksheet!

How to trigger this Event?

Comment: Are the other workbook events working properly? 
I think you should better use sheet_recalculate

Comment: If you want everything to calculate then use `Application.CalculateFull` or even `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`

Comment: @TSion.D.P, There is no event in VBA called: (sheet_recalculate), and the other events work properly!

Comment: @TimWilliams, What I need is to trigger this event that contains some commands: (Workbook_SheetCalculate) each time I recalculate the worksheets!

Comment: @HaythamAmairah did you looked up [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-sheetcalculate-event-excel)? According to MSDN event should fire when a (work)sheet recalculates in workbook. Maybe you have `Application.EnableEvents = False`?

Comment: Maybe if you update tour question with some more detailed information, so as your code and how you're triggering a worksheet recalculation, someone might be able to help.  Without that, you're not going to get any more information then people have already provided.

Comment: Things seem to be getting clearer. I thought this event should trigger as soon as I press F9, In fact, I tested it in an empty workbook, but when I add some formulas to the workbook, it works just fine.

If I have a volatile function it works with all kind of recalculations, but with others, it works only with full recalculation!

Thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example, in the worksheet for the event have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
 MsgBox "Calculating"
End Sub
```

Then in the sheet, in any cell, enter `=RAND()`

The formula causes a recalculation and triggers the event.

Or from a standard module use the following:

```
Public Sub Test()

'Application.Calculate   ''could use this event for the workbook

With Worksheets("Sheet5") 'sheet containing the event code

    .Calculate

End With

End Sub
```

The key seems to be that there is something in the sheet to calculate e.g. `=RAND()`.

I remembered from another post, at some point, a link to the following [Excel’s Smart Recalculation Engine](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecrets.htm)

A quick extract says:

> Excel normally only calculates the minimum number of cells possible.
>
> Excel’s smart recalculation engine normally minimises calculation
>   time   by tracking changes and only recalculating
>
> - Cells, formulae, values or names that have changed or are flagged as needing recalculation.
> - Cells dependent on other cells, formulae, names or values that need recalculation.

So, if you just had constants in the sheet, even if you issue a Worksheet.Calculate the msgbox wouldn't appear. You could test this by removing the `=RAND()` from the sheet and just putting `1` in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

If I have two sheets each with a single non-volatile formula, and this in the workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Debug.Print Sh.Name
End Sub
```

I see both sheets names on calling:

```
Application.CalculateFull
```

or:

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

but no output with:

```
Application.Calculate
```

If I add a volatile formula to one of the sheets then I get that sheet when calling `Application.Calculate`.

If you're still having problems then you'd need to post a few more details including your event code and what types of formulas you have on your sheets.